# WPF Adorners - Best practices to use a single adorner upon multiple objects and Enable or Dissable it based upon policy

Tags: wpf, user-interface, architecture

I have created few adorners for specific type of objects.

Now my business analyst requirement changed that -

```
1. adorners should be possible to dynamically enabled or disabled. 
2. A single adorner should be re-usable upon multiple or all objects. 
3. Cues should be very user friendly utilize the page real estate so efficiently, 
  so that user do not have to go for property editor window as this looses visual from actual object.
```

Please suggest me the best practices, Designs and samples that i need to refer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- In order to dynamically enable or dissable the adorners, i found the policy based approach is good.
- I found WPF Designer Extensibility framework is good which easy to deine various policy such as 
  (primary selection policy, etc.. etc..).
- Based upon the objects behavior the correpsonding policy servers will apply or remove adorners on the object.